# Java Base64 encoded byte array to javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: java, apache-axis

I have written a method that encodes a given PDF-file into a byte array:

```
public static byte[] encodeFileToBase64(String pathToPdfFile)
        throws IOException {
    File file = new File(pathToPdfFile);

    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw (e);
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int bytesRead;
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw (e);
    }

    input.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Now I am implementing an interface to an SOAP webservice.

The user manual demands a PDF file in Base64 encoding.

I have generated Java code from the given `wsdl` file with Apache Axis2 (`wsdl2java`). In this code, it is required to set the given PDF file as `javax.activation.DataHandler`:

```
/**
 * Auto generated setter method
 * @param param PdfDocument
 */
public void setPdfDocument(javax.activation.DataHandler param) {
    this.localPdfDocument = param;
}
```

Now, my question is, how to get the Base64 encoded stuff into a `DataHandler`.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("filePath");
request.setMessageFile(new DataHandler(fds));
```

the javax.activation.* package handle the base64 encoding natively.